# Firebase Dynamic Links MinimumVersion behavior

Tags: firebase-dynamic-links

I'm creating Firebase Dynamic Links programmatically in an Android and iOS apps.
Both apps are already available in Google Play and the App Store, so I want to use MinimumVersion to redirect users to the appropriate store if they are using previous versions.

The iOS parameters documentation states:

> The version number of the minimum version of your app that can open the link. This flag is passed to your app when it is opened, and your app must decide what to do with it.

So if I understand it correctly, previous version would not be able to use it, as the code to decide what to do with it, doesn't exist in the current iOS version?

The Android parameters documentation states:

> The versionCode of the minimum version of your app that can open the link. If the installed app is an older version, the user is taken to the Play Store to upgrade the app.

But when I try it, the Android device still suggests the current app to handle the intent, and doesn't redirect the user to upgrade it.
When I choose the app it opens it instead of redirecting.

What can cause this behavior?

Am I missing something in my understanding of how Firebase Dynamic Links suppose to work?